# jQuery - backup / cache an element's events?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to backup all of the events that are set on any given element?

Backstory: I've got some code that shows an absolutely positioned 'popup' of sorts when a user mouses over a certain icon (think on-hover help text). If the user mouses over the popup, it sticks around, but if they mouse off of the popup or the icon, the popup hides. This is all working as intended. However the popup also has some form elements inside of it (don't ask) and if the user starts to fill out the form, I'd like to remove the mouseleave event that hides the popup so that they don't accidentally mouse off and lose their data. Terrible UX aside, this is fairly easy to do, but the kicker is that I want to re-add that mouseleave functionality once the user submits the form or clicks the icon.

Pseudocode:

```
var event_backup;
var icon = $("img#icon");
var popup = $("div#popup");

icon.bind("mouseenter"):    
    popup.show();
icon.bind("mouseleave"):
    popup.hide();
icon.bind("click"):
    popup.hide();
    popup.events = event_backup; //how do I do this?

popup.bind("mouseleave"):
    popup.hide();
popup.bind(...):
    //lots of bind events for popup that I want to keep
    //I'd rather not duplicate code and manually re-add these later

popup.children("form input").bind("focus"):
    event_backup = popup.events; //how do I do this?
    popup.unbind();
popup.children("form input#done_button").bind("click"):
    popup.events = event_backup; //how do I do this?
```

Hopefully that makes sense, and apologies if this is a dumb question... it's been a long day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be better to just have a flag, and at the beginning of relevant functions perform a simple check if you can:

```
if (skipHover) return;
```

If in any case you want access to bound events:

```
popup.data('events').click
```

is an array of bound functions, and so too for other event names.

Comment: Thanks! After taking a break and looking at my code again I went back and added a flag of sorts when the user clicks the form. When they click the form I add a "focused" class to the parent, and I modified my mouseleave event to check for the "focused" class and only hide the popup if the "focused" class isn't present. Clicking the icon or submitting the form then removes the "focused" class.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting all your code inside of `bind` you could try separating it out into it's own function. That way it should be easier to bind and you can also reference it. for example:

```
var popupBind = function(el) {
    //some code in here, however long you want
    //we can reference the element triggering the event with 'el'
}

//now we can use this in our bind calls

popup.bind("click",
    function() {
        popupBind($(this));
    }
);
```

Comment: Ah I knew it was just me being dumb after a long day, better code organization like you've just shown would've completely avoided this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that manages the binds for the icon. Then you can unbind, and simply re-run the function when you need to bind all the events again.

```
var popup = $("div#popup");

function bind_popup() {
  popup.bind(blah);
  ...
}

bind_popup();

popup.children("form input").focus(function() {
  popup.unbind();
});
popup.children("form input#done_button").click(function() {
  bind_popup();
});
```

I prefer the flag idea in davin's answer though.